# What is causing the Listen error in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I did some changes in the schema.rb file and as far as I think, that is what caused this error. Also I think I deleted some migration files improperly.

```
FATAL: Listen error: unable to monitor directories for changes.
```

Its coming on every rails command I use on the terminal

I have seen this as the solution everywhere

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

But I don't get what it does. Could someone explain what is going on here. As in what is the solution doing and what actually caused this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the about inotify: [inotify man page](https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify)

The inotify API provides a mechanism for monitoring file system events. Inotify can be used to monitor individual files, or to monitor directories. When a directory is monitored, inotify will return events for the directory itself, and for files inside the directory.

It's not uncommon to encounter a system limit on the number of files you can monitor.

You can get your current inotify file watch limit by executing:

`$ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`

> */proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches*
>
> This specifies an upper limit on the number of watches that can be
> created per real user ID.

When this limit is not enough to monitor all files inside a directory, the limit must be increased.

You can set a new limit temporary with:

```
$ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

If you like to make your limit permanent, use:

```
$ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

The `gem listen` has ran into this limit, so you'll need to increase you it...

[Listen gem wiki](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers)

Comment: Oh okay. Also could you explain why this limit could have  exceeded. Did tampering the schema.rb file do something?

Comment: No i dont believe this had anything to do with the schema most likely you added more files or directories to your app

Comment: How about the number 524288 in your answer?

Comment: @giahuy the number specifies an upper limit on the number of watches that can be created per real user ID.